# Workflow to change order status if a custom field is populated for Sales Orders in NetSuite

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript

Basically I want the orders to import under `Pending Fulfillment` only when the selected triggering client field has a value in it (any value). If it is blank I don't want this workflow to run on that SO. I have another workflow in place that affects other orders that are imported through Web Services, so this will be just for specific orders when the Triggering Client Field has a value. I set it up, as you can see in the images attached and no luck!

> Parameters: Order Status=Pending Fulfillment (Static value)
>
> Trigger on: After Field Sourcing
>
> Contexts: Web Services
>
> Triggering Client Fields: Custom free form text field that will be
>   populated with a 4-5 digit number

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it will only work within the UI when someone is entering a sales order - and actually it won't work at all because if that's a free form text field, then it won't trigger the "After Field Sourcing" event. I would make the trigger Before Record Submit, or After Record Submit instead, and then under the "Condition" section, use the visual builder to tell set the criteria to only when Handshake Order ID is not empty. That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks Alex, tried both of these and still no luck. Im thinking it has something to do with my Workflow Actions Conditions. Currently it looks like this: Sales Order : Handshake Order ID Is Not Empty or formulaic version: {salesorder.custbody11} is not null

Answer (score 0):

Please change your workflow action as below

Workflow Action : Import Status

Trigger On : Entry

Condition : {custbody11} is not null